# AngularFire How to unsubscribe from Firebase Real time database

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I use AngularFire library to read data from Firebase Realtime database. Below is the code that I used to subscribe for real time data changes

```
// db is a reference to AngularFireDatabase
this.dbSubscription = db.list('/authors').valueChanges().subscribe(items =>
```

For some user actions I have to change the path that I'm listening data. So the code looks like this

```
this.dbSubscription.unsubscribe();
this.dbSubscription = db.list('/books').valueChanges().subscribe(items =>
```

Is calling `this.dbSubscription.unsubscribe();`detach the application from the database so that any data changes happen to the the previous path, i.e. /authors does not sync with the application once it is subscribed to new path /books ? I want to make sure that the data that I'm not interested are not downloaded to the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your thinking.

`AngularFire` does not have an API function such as `off()` like the regular [JavaScript library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#detach_listeners) does. `off()`, in the JavaScript library,  would be used remove the listener on the database.

Using `unsubscribe()` is the correct way to achieve what you want in `AngularFire`.

More can be read [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/380).

Answer (score 4):

Yep! Calling unsubscribe will in fact call the `.off()` method under the hood. You can see it [here in the source code](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/database/observable/fromRef.ts#L26).

```
  return new Observable<SnapshotPrevKey>(subscriber => {
    const fn = ref[listenType](event, (snapshot, prevKey) => {
      subscriber.next({ snapshot, prevKey });
      if (listenType == 'once') { subscriber.complete(); }
    }, subscriber.error.bind(subscriber));
    if (listenType == 'on') {
      // return a method for unsubscribing the listener
      return { unsubscribe() { ref.off(event, fn)} };
    } else {
      return { unsubscribe() { } };
    }
  })
```